# Multi-label image classification vs. object detection

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection, image-classification

For my next TF2-based computer vision project I need to classify images to a pre-defined set of classes. However, multiple objects of different classes can occur on one such image. That sounds like an object detection task, so I guess I could go for that.

But: I don't need to know where on an image each of these objects are, I just need to know which classes of objects are visible on an image.

Now I am thinking which route I should take. I am in particular interested in a high accuracy/quality of the solution. So I would prefer the approach that leads to better results. Thus from your experience, should I still go for an object detector, even though I don't need to know the location of the detected objects on the image, or should I rather build an image classifier, which could output all the classes that are located on an image? Is this even an option, can a "normal" classifier output multiple classes?

Comment: That's neither multi-class nor object detection. It's multi-label classification. If you want to detect objects in an image, you need to draw bounding boxes around it which is completely unnecessary for your problem. [Here is an example](https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-sCcOrQsTH9Q/XG1yv7mhERI/AAAAAAAAAJI/aEj6Jf1lookERHqPQS_Y6Q9bxBcTV7TIwCLcBGAs/s1600/multiclass-multilabel.png)

Comment: Yes, it is possible. This is literally called multi-class multi-label detection and you can find a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49358088/does-tensorflows-object-detection-api-support-multi-class-multi-label-detection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't need the object localization, stick to classification only.

Although you will be tempted to use the standard off-the-shelf network of multi-class multi-label object detection because of its re-usability, but realize that you are asking the model to do more things. If you have tons of data - not a problem. Or if your objects are similar to the ones used in ImageNet/COCO etc, you can simply use standard off-the-shelf object detection architecture and fine-tune on your dataset.

However, if you have **less data and you need to train from scratch** (e.g. medical images, weird objects), then object detection will be an overkill and will give you inferior results.

Remember, most of the object detection networks re-cycle the classification architectures with modifications added to last layers to incorporate additional outputs for object detection coordinates. There is a loss function associated with those additional outputs. During training in order to get best loss value, some of the classification accuracy is compromised for the sake of getting better object localization coordinates. You don't need that compromise. So, you can modify the last layer of object detection network and remove the outputs for coordinates.

Again, all this hassle is worth only if you have less data and you really need to train from scratch.