# How to perform object detection model training on more than 1 class?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

Link: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/colab_tutorials/eager_few_shot_od_training_tf2_colab.ipynb

I have tried the above google colab to train a object detection model with 1 class as shown in the example.

I am trying to understand how to modify this code to be able to train 2 classes.

In the above example, after I annotate the image with boxes, it runs the following code to create the `category_index` and image/box tensors. Suppose I modify the `num_classes = 2` and add another class to the `category_index`, then how to proceed from here? For example - I believe the one-hot encoding is for 1-class only. How to modify the code to make it work with 2 classes?

```
# By convention, our non-background classes start counting at 1.  Given
# that we will be predicting just one class, we will therefore assign it a
# `class id` of 1.
duck_class_id = 1
num_classes = 1

category_index = {duck_class_id: {'id': duck_class_id, 'name': 'rubber_ducky'}}

# Convert class labels to one-hot; convert everything to tensors.
# The `label_id_offset` here shifts all classes by a certain number of indices;
# we do this here so that the model receives one-hot labels where non-background
# classes start counting at the zeroth index.  This is ordinarily just handled
# automatically in our training binaries, but we need to reproduce it here.
label_id_offset = 1
train_image_tensors = []
gt_classes_one_hot_tensors = []
gt_box_tensors = []
for (train_image_np, gt_box_np) in zip(
    train_images_np, gt_boxes):
  train_image_tensors.append(tf.expand_dims(tf.convert_to_tensor(
      train_image_np, dtype=tf.float32), axis=0))
  gt_box_tensors.append(tf.convert_to_tensor(gt_box_np, dtype=tf.float32))
  zero_indexed_groundtruth_classes = tf.convert_to_tensor(
      np.ones(shape=[gt_box_np.shape[0]], dtype=np.int32) - label_id_offset)
  gt_classes_one_hot_tensors.append(tf.one_hot(
      zero_indexed_groundtruth_classes, num_classes))
print('Done prepping data.')
```

Comment: One hot encoding for one class will look like this. `[bg, class1]`.
For 2 classes, the encoding vector will be `[bg, class1, class2]`.

Comment: In my example how do I annotate the images and tell the code that which images belong to class 1 and which images belong to class 2?

Comment: For annotation, you need an annotation tool like CVAT maybe.

Answer (score 1):

In order for the ***mono-class*** detection detection tutorial: [Rubber Ducky detector](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/colab_tutorials/eager_few_shot_od_training_tf2_colab.ipynb) or [Zombie detector](https://github.com/ashishpatel26/TensorFlow-Advanced-Techniques-Specialization/blob/main/Course%203%20-%20Advanced%20Computer%20Vision%20with%20TensorFlow/Week%202/C3W2_Assignment.ipynb) . Change it to work with ***multi-class***, changes like these need to be made:

- The `category_index` variable has to look like this. (get very good example: [category_index example](https://rockyshikoku.medium.com/how-to-use-tensorflow-object-detection-api-with-the-colab-sample-notebooks-477707fadf1b) )

```py
    # Array of paths to the images
    train_image_filenames = [
          './datasets/train_images/train_image0001.jpg',
          './datasets/train_images/train_image0002.jpg'
          ]
    # Label map ids start from "1"
    category_index = {
         1: {'id': 1, 'name': 'cat'},
         2: {'id': 2, 'name': 'dog'}
         }
    # Array of IDs
    Gt_labels = [
        np.array([1,1]),
        np.array([1,2,2])
        ]   
    # Bounding boxes. Numpy array of [ miny, minx, maxy, maxx ] 
    Gt_boxes = [
         np.array([[0.436, 0.591, 0.629, 0.712],[0.539, 0.583, 0.73, 0.71]], dtype=np.float32),
         np.array([[0.464, 0.414, 0.626, 0.548],[0.313, 0.308, 0.648, 0.526],[0.256, 0.444, 0.484, 0.629]], dtype=np.float32)
        ]
    NUM_CLASSES = len(category_index)
```

- Here the `np.ones(shape=[gt_box_np.shape[0]], dtype=np.int32)` ***is non-sense*** (also in [Rubber Ducky detector](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/colab_tutorials/eager_few_shot_od_training_tf2_colab.ipynb) ), it is a very awkward way the author has found to *format* the grount true classes variable as a tensor. the **GT_classes** entry must be in the format `Tensor("Const:0", shape=(1, NUM_CLASES), dtype=float32)` and **one_hot encoder** *(float32 is important)* .
- For it, must be replaced by both: `tf.one_hot` and with `tf.reshape`. Example creation correct `gt_classes_one_hot_tensors`:

```py
LABEL_ID_OFFSET = 1
train_image_tensors = []
gt_classes_one_hot_tensors = []
gt_box_tensors = []
# One memory-costly process is the internal conversion from (usually) numpy to tf.tensor. If you are sure that your GPU should be able to handle the batches:
# Manually convert the data to tf tensors using the CPU RAM, and only then pass it to your model (eventually using GPU).
print("\nUse CPU, GPU dont have space to locate one_hot_tensors. Use for hot_encoders:", str(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('CPU')[0]))
with tf.device('/cpu:0'): # Recomended for this step Use CPU, if GPU dont have space
    for (train_image_np, gt_box_np, gt_label_np) in zip(train_images_np, Gt_boxes, Gt_labels):
        print("|", end="")
        train_image_tensors.append(tf.expand_dims(tf.convert_to_tensor(train_image_np, dtype=tf.float32), axis=0)) # image in np format train_image_np 
        gt_box_tensors.append(tf.convert_to_tensor(gt_box_np, dtype=tf.float32)) # put box in Tensor
        zero_indexed_groundtruth_classes = tf.convert_to_tensor(gt_label_np - LABEL_ID_OFFSET) # put labels in Numpy array (min:0)
        gt_classes_one_hot_tensors.append(tf.one_hot(zero_indexed_groundtruth_classes, num_classes)) # label Tensor to one hot
print('Done prepping data. Num Data: ',len(train_images_np), "\n" )
```

More Info  and ***full example*** [full example](https://rockyshikoku.medium.com/how-to-use-tensorflow-object-detection-api-with-the-colab-sample-notebooks-477707fadf1b)  extra github [example link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/9655#issuecomment-1460289284)

TIP: If you are starting with these tutorials [Rubber Ducky detector](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/colab_tutorials/eager_few_shot_od_training_tf2_colab.ipynb), I recommend you to read: [Does tensorflow's object detection api support multi-class multi-label detection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49358088/does-tensorflows-object-detection-api-support-multi-class-multi-label-detection/75275213#75275213)

***Warning***, in case you want to use it for multi bounding boxes ([n,4] boxes): [warn important](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61647404/tensorflow-2-getting-warningtensorflow9-out-of-the-last-9-calls-to-function/77811613#77811613)